# Powerbuilder tree nodes selected row colours

Tags: tree, treeview, row, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a tree view DataWindow an when I select a row in ,it, highlights the entire row with the colour blue. How can I set the colour from blue to transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the blue color comes from a call to `SelectRow(row_number, true)` in a `clicked()` event.

It is dedicated to highlight the line and it is not the same as `SetRow()`. Just don't call `SelectRow()`.